# Sort Chinese contacts like in Contact app

Tags: ios, chinese-locale, uilocalizedcollation

I am making an iOS app with contacts and I want to sort my contacts the same way as in the iPhone Contacts app.

What I mean is that if the contact is 试命名, (which according to Google Translate translates to Test Name) this is sorted under letter S in the Contacts.app when the chosen iPhone language is Chinese (Simplified).

So the Contacts.app knows how to map the Chinese characters to their phonetic correspondent in the English alphabet. How would I do that in my app?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/7589528#7589528 is one way. You would include an additional field for a phonetic spelling.